# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...sqk3urlRSf0SyulYvOMeZ'

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules

When i try to install any package into my React App, I get this error. I had deleted node modules and reinstall it but the problem remains there. when I run `node cache verify` it does nothing. I had also run `npm cache clean --force`, but nothing happened.  A warning message showed `npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.` but nothing execute

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. sudo npm cache clean --force
2. sudo npm cache verify
3. sudo npm i npm@latest -g

Let me know this resolves your issue.